# C# project with unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm writing Master's thesis. I nead some open source projects (written in C#) with unit tests (NUnit or MSTest) for my experiments. Anyone knows, where can I download these projects?

Comment: What do you mean by open source? Two Patterns & Practices projects I know of (Enterprise Library and the Service Factory) come with source and extensive unit tests.

Comment: Doesn't NUnit contain unit tests for itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also often use: [Data Structures and Algorithms](http://dsa.codeplex.com), [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com), [KBCsv](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/), [Codekicker.BBCode](http://bbcode.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[ASP.Net MVC](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC&referringTitle=Home) source code from Microsoft
[Sharp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) is a good reference architecture for ASP.Net MVC.
Microsoft Spain has a released a [reference atchitecture](http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/) with unit testing using Pex and Moles.

All the above projects have extensive well written unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Check out codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385902%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) concerning unit testing? There's a walkthrough that might be handy.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is trying to perform some research based on existing implementations of unit test suites.  (as opposed to trying to learn what unit testing is all about)